# PKCS11 Wildfly 13 - Certificado digital

Tags: java, certificado-digital, wildfly13

Estou tentando utilizar a seguinte biblioteca: https://github.com/Samuel-Oliveira

Pra utilizá-la, é necessária carregar um certificado digital, no caso, do tipo A1.

Ao tentar utilizá-la com uma classe normal com um `public static void main` funciona normalmente. Tenho um jar do meu projeto que utilizo o tempo todo.

Acontece que utilizando a biblioteca num projeto web `<package>war</package>` e deployando no `Wildfly(versão 13)`, ao tentar carregar o certificado: `CertificadoService.certificadoPfx(path, pass);`

estoura essa Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/pkcs11/wrapper/PKCS11Exception
```

Segue classe:

```
@Singleton
public class Worker {

    private AtomicBoolean busy = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public void work() {
        if (!busy.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            System.out.println("Executing this task at " + new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()) + ".");

            String path = "/home/user/certificado.pfx";
            String pass = "4321";


            CertificadoService.certificadoPfx(path, pass);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            busy.set(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Algumas classes da JRE não são carregadas de forma padrão pelo WildFly. Umas delas são as requeridas pela API pra carregar o certificado digital programaticamente.

É necessário, então, forçar o carregamento das mesmas pelo arquivo

**jboss-deployment-structure.xml**

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <system export="true">
                <paths>
                    <path name="sun/security/x509"/>
                    <path name="sun/security/pkcs11"/>
                    <path name="sun/security/pkcs11/wrapper"/>
                </paths>
            </system>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```